# How to add generators that respect alphabetical orders

Tags: ruby, generator

I created a generator it generates some files and adds some content into a file; I want it to also respect the alphabetical order of names in the file.

Example is: when I want to generate a new action I'll run `rails g new_action drying_clothes`. This will generate files with content and write into an existing file. This file has actions like:
`Cooking Pottery Soaking`.

If I currently run the generator the action/ name `drying_clothes` will be inserted after `Soaking`, how can I ensure it respects alphabetical order? Here's my code so far:

```
def add_action
  inject_into_file 'app/actions.yml',
                    "#{file_name}\n
                      category: new\n"
end
```

Comment: You'll have to read all the contents, sort them, and then write them back out.

Comment: Yeah, how can I do that?